# Nested OpenMP parallel regions not iterating as expected

Tags: fortran, openmp

This is probably a dumb question, but I'm just starting out with OpenMP due to increased data volumes.

I'm going through "Parallel Programming in Fortran 95 using OpenMP" by Miguel Hermanns and am very early in the book.  One of the early examples shows the use of nested parallel regions and indicates that it should produce N<sup>2</sup> + N lines of output.  The procedure looks like this:

```
program helloworld
    !$OMP PARALLEL
        write(*,*) "Hello"
        !$OMP PARALLEL
            write(*,*) "Hi"
        !$OMP END PARALLEL
    !$OMP END PARALLEL
end program helloworldcode
```

I would expect 12 Hellos and 144 His, but instead I get 12 of each:

```
$ ./helloworld.exe 
 Hello
 Hello
 Hello
 Hi
 Hi
 Hello
 Hello
 Hello
 Hello
 Hello
 Hello
 Hi
 Hi
 Hello
 Hello
 Hi
 Hi
 Hi
 Hi
 Hi
 Hello
 Hi
 Hi
 Hi
```

Why am I not getting the 156 lines of output that I would expect?

Comment: Ues tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You can add a version tag for version specific question (this one is not Fortran version specific at all). And even the book you are citing is F95 and not F90...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, OpenMP serializes all the nested parallel regions in order to prevent the worst case of quadratic over-subscription when N^2 worker threads are created. With big enough number of processors (say >=16), quadratic over-subscription can ruin execution with nightmare overheads or cause resource exhaustion issue when requested number of threads just cannot be created.

For information how to enable nested parallelism in OpenMP on your risk, please refer to [omp_set_nested](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fset_005fnested.html#omp_005fset_005fnested) and corresponding environment variable [OMP_NESTED](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fNESTED.html#OMP_005fNESTED).

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks.  If I wanted to, is there a flag to tell it to run nested parallel regions as they are written?